# Program stops after I add more if statements

Tags: if-statement, arduino, gyroscope, servo

Recently I've been having a problem where I add 2 more if statements and it stops my code all together. For example, the code below will work with the two gyroX if statements but once I add those two gyroY if statements the whole code won't run. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue would be appreciated.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo4;

int pos1 = 0;
int pos2 = 0;

long gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  setupMPU();
  servo1.attach(4);
  servo2.attach(5);
  servo3.attach(6);
  servo4.attach(7);
}

void loop() { 
  recordGyroRegisters();
  if(gyroX <= 0)
  {
      pos1 += 1;
      servo1.writeMicroseconds(pos1);
      servo3.writeMicroseconds(pos1);
  }
  if(gyroX > 0)
  {
      pos1 -= 1;
      servo1.writeMicroseconds(pos1);
      servo3.writeMicroseconds(pos1);
  }
  if(gyroY <= 0)  //PROBLEM OCCURS WHEN I ADD THIS FUNCTION
  {
      pos2 += 1;
      servo2.writeMicroseconds(pos2);
      servo4.writeMicroseconds(pos2);
  }
  if(gyroY > 0)   //PROBLEM OCCURS WHEN I ADD THIS FUNCTION
  {
      pos2 -= 1;
      servo2.writeMicroseconds(pos2);
      servo4.writeMicroseconds(pos2);
  }
}

void setupMPU(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); 
  Wire.write(0x6B); 
  Wire.write(0b00000000); 
  Wire.endTransmission();  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); 
  Wire.write(0x1B); 
  Wire.write(0x00000000); 
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000);
  Wire.write(0x1C);  
  Wire.write(0b00000000); 
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
}

void recordGyroRegisters() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000);
  Wire.write(0x3B); 
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0b1101000,6);
  while(Wire.available() < 6);
  gyroX = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
  gyroY = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); 
  gyroZ = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); 
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with that part of the code that should cause a hangup.  How are you powering the Servos?  If you're drawing power through the Arduino you may be drawing too much when the second set of servos tries to move and shutting down the board.  Give us a schematic of the project.

Comment: They are powered independent of the Arduino. It's also worth mentioning that I have had all four servos moving at one time.

Comment: If they are powered independent, do you have a common ground?

Comment: How does it exactly hang? Do you comment out only the if-statements or also the part in ```recordGyroRegisters()```? Consider adding a debug print with the contents of the ```long``` variables.

Comment: Yes, the servos are wired in parallel to the same battery. So they have a common ground.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you not using `else if`?
It will work faster.

```
if(gyroX <= 0)
{
  ...
}
else if(gyroX > 0)
{
}

if(gyroY <= 0)  //PROBLEM OCCURS WHEN I ADD THIS FUNCTION
{
}
else if(gyroY > 0)   //PROBLEM OCCURS WHEN I ADD THIS FUNCTION
{
}
```